# Common coding language for Sphero developers?

Tags: sphero

I just discovered Sphero and I love this little ball, so I want to develop apps!

Is there a common coding language that most of Sphero's app developers use so that I can learn it and start building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From glancing over this page http://developer.gosphero.com. You can use Java for developing on the Android platform and Objective-C for iOS. Looks like there is also a plugin for Unity that uses C#.

That webpage also contains guides for the individual platforms and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **ruby** with artoo framework: http://artoo.io/documentation/platforms/sphero/ or **javascript** with cylon framework: http://cylonjs.com/documentation/platforms/sphero/ or even **go**, with gobot.io/documentation/platforms/sphero/ framework too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python, there are 2 options beyond the ROS Python plugin currently listed on the developer page.

1. SpheroNav

SpheroNav was written by Simon Nistad for his master's thesis in 2014, designed to support the control of multiple Spheros. I have forked his code, and will be extending it in upcoming months.

https://github.com/hydrosquall/SpheroNav

2. Kulka

This is a project by Karol Szuster, aimed at new programmers. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get his example code to work on my windows laptop, but maybe you'll have better luck.

https://github.com/zdanowiczkonrad/PythonSphero